# Multiple integral over General Domains

Tags: integration

This is a rather general question but I am having trouble conceptualizing the integral. 
Say that we for the function $f(x,y)$ we integrate $y$ over $v(x)$ and $u(x)$ and $x$ over an interval of constants $\left[a,b \right]$.

Then what exactly does the integral measure? Since we are integrating over a function is it the area of the function that lies between those points? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We measure the volume under the surface of $f(x, y)$. See this picture (courtesy of [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_integral)):

[image]

The rectangular region at the bottom is the domain of integration. The surface at the top is the graph of the function $f(x, y) = x^2 - y^2$. The volume is the double integral.

Comment: Okay but how does that change if we integrate $f(x,y)$ over functions of $x$ and/or $y$?

Comment: @Ioannis Intuitively speaking, when you integrate over $y$ as you describe, you evaluate the area of a "slice" of the body along the $y$ axis between $v(x)$ and $u(x)$. When you integrate the result over $x$, you get the total volume.

Comment: Oh I see. Is that why sometimes we present $y=f(x)$ in two dimensions and then calculate the volume with double integrals?

Comment: The idea is similar (assuming you're talking about [solids of revolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_of_revolution)). Of course, this intuitive idea can be made precise with theorems from analysis.

Comment: Thank you very much Ayman Hourieh.

Comment: @Ioannis Happy to help!